# Chef recipe to remote copy a directory

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I just want to run this recipe:

```
remote_file "#{ENV['HOMEDRIVE']}/chef/cookbooks" do
  source "http://161.134.22.123/cookbooks"
end
```

I have been trying to get the chef command Remote_File to work with a directory, it gives me

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - C:/chef/cookbooks
```

The Remote_Directory command doesn't let me specify the location of the server I want to access.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to copy the cookbooks directory from a remote location

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't totally answer you question, but the remote_directory resource only applies directories which are stored in the /files/[default,etc] directories.  In order to pull a full directory from an http resource, I think you will need to build a script resource which knows how to walk the remote directory.  The actual remote_directory resource does indeed have a somewhat confusing name, and I think it is an artifact from a time when remote_file both pulled http resources as well as cookbook files

HTH

Answer (score 0):

may be you are running commands using "user" mode. Try using "root" mode.